# getting XML Catalog to work with wsimport. JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6

Tags: xml, schema, catalog, wsimport

I have not had problems with xjc or tools like oxygen and eclipse xml plugin with my catalogs, but can't seem to find a flavor that works with the wsimport command.

Using the namespace for resolution  the following entries work for xjc but not wsimport.

> <public publicId="http://schemas.ticomgeo.com/2010/geonet/common/ServiceMessageTypes/v0"  uri="./MessageTypes/ServiceMessageTypes.xsd"/>

Here are the commands I issued

> xjc /data/catalog.work/wsdefs/HSTypes/HealthAndStatusV1.xsd  -catalog /data/catalog.work/wsdefs/catalog3.xml
>
> wsimport -verbose /data/catalog.work/wsdefs/HealthAndStatusServiceV1.wsdl -catalog /data/catalog.work/wsdefs/catalog5.xml

The error I get in the wsimport shows it is not mapping the schema location. It  only looks for it relative to the catalog or wsdl  home directory ( they are the same ).

> [ERROR] /data/catalog.work/wsdefs/ServiceMessageTypes.xsd (No such file or directory)

Here is the import statment in the wsdl

```
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:import
           namespace="http://schemas.ticomgeo.com/2010/geonet/common/ServiceMessageTypes/v0"
            schemaLocation="ServiceMessageTypes.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
```

Using the following entry in the catalog file again processing works with xjc

> <systemSuffix  systemIdSuffix="ServiceMessageTypes.xsd"  uri="./MessageTypes/ServiceMessageTypes.xsd"/>

However using wsimport I get errors similar to the following on every element. The first error line number refers the line numoer of the start of the element following endpointStatusEnumType and the second error line number refers to the start of the EndpointStatusEnumType element Note that it is resolving the file location to get to the schema.

> [ERROR] 'EndpointStatusEnumType' is already defined
>    line 38 of file:/data/catalog.work/wsdefs/MessageTypes/ServiceMessageTypes.xsd
>
> [ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
>    line 23 of file:/data/catalog.work/wsdefs/MessageTypes/ServiceMessageTypes.xsd
>
> 23  <xs:simpleType name="EndpointStatusEnumType">
>          
>              The current status of a web service's endpoint.>
>
> ```
>    </xs:annotation>
>    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
>      <xs:enumeration value="NORMAL"/>
>       <xs:enumeration value="COMMS_ERROR"/>
>         <xs:enumeration value="DISABLED"/>
>     </xs:restriction>
> </xs:simpleType>
>
>
>
> <!-- Complex Types -->
> <!-- -->
> ```
>
> 38    <xs:complexType name="HeaderType">"

Besides working with xjc both formats also work with the OXYGEN and Eclipse XML editors and validators.

I assume that wsimport calls the same code as xjc so I am guessing there is something broken in how I import the schemas into the wsdl file, but its a pretty straight forward  or a bug in the version of wsimport I am using.

wsimport -version
JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6

xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6" 
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)

Anyone have suggestions on how to get catalogs to work with wsimport?